# Field extension more general definition

Tags: category-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

we can define a field extension as $K$ is a subset(!) of $L$ both fields, and the same $1$ and same operation (just restricting).
But The Stacks project defines a field extension as a morphism $i: K\to L$, which is necessarily injective. Hence one can identify $K$ with $i(K)$ as a subfield of $L$.

Is this more general definition compatible with all results of Galois Theory? For example one can define separability for $i: K\to L$ in the obvious way, which will be equivalent to $L/i(K)$ is separable.
Or should I just ignore this definition because I have always to carry the injective morphism with me (imagine we have a tower of extensions... That would be annoying.)

Comment: As you say, you can identify $K$ with its image in $L$. You can rewrite all of Galois theory using field embeddings instead of literal subfields, but as you say, it ends up being cumbersome.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you very much. Your comment should be an answer. One question remains: How do you know that we can rewrite all of Galois theory using this definition and ends up with the same results?

Comment: I don't know which version of Galois theory you have learnt. For me, a field extension $L/K$ is called Galois if and only if the number of $K$-automorphisms of $L$ is equal to the degree of the extension. This version works fine with "field extensions". A subfield $K \subset L$ is in fact a special kind of extension: the map $i: K \rightarrow L$ sends any $x$ to $x$ itself. Extensions are actually more convenient to use for Galois theory, as e.g. one can talk about the extension $i: k(t) \rightarrow k(t)$ sending $t$ to $t^2$.

Comment: @WhatsUp So you learned Galois Theory with the defintion ,,A field extension is a morphism from $K$ to $L$" ??

Comment: I didn't remember which version I learned first, but I'm sure that the version you mentioned exists.